# $y'' - y = 0 $ for $0<x<1; y(0) = 1, y(1) = -4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is an odd numbered problem from my textbook, so I have the solution I'm just curious as to how one gets the answer?

Can someone walk me through it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

For our characteristic equation, we have:

$$m^2 - 1 = 0 \rightarrow m_1 = -1, m_2 = 1$$

This means our solution is:

$$y = c_1e^{-x} + c_2 e^x$$

Plug in the initial conditions to solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

- $y(0) = c_1 + c_2 = 1$
- $y(1) = c_1e^{-1} + c_2e = -4$

Upon solving these, we arrive at:

- $c_1 = \dfrac{4e +1}{e^2-1} +1$
- $c_2 = -\dfrac{4e+1}{e^2-1}$

You should be able to handle it from here.

We can look at the solution curve as:

[image]

We can also look at the phase portrait as:

[image]

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti. $(+1)$

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks - happy POETS day! :-)

Comment: @Amzoti: +1 but what is that day?

Comment: @BabakS.: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POETS_day. Regards

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard CCLDE, or constant coefficient linear differential equation, so we use the characteristic equation to solve it:

Let $y'' - y = 0$. The characteristic polynomial is:

$\lambda^{2} - 1 = 0$

So our roots are:

$\lambda = \pm 1$

Which means our fundamental set of solutions is:

$\{e^{1x}, e^{-1x}\} = \{e^{x}, e^{-x}\}$

Hence, our general solution takes the form:

$y = C_{1}e^{x} + C_{2}e^{-x}$

Plugging into the equation with known values to determine $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$, we find:

$y(0) = C_{1} + C_{2} = 1 \implies C_{1} = 1-C_{2}$

$y(1) = C_{1}e + C_{2}e^{-1} = (1-C_{2})e + C_{2}e^{-1} = -4$

So

$\frac{e^{2}-1}{e}(C_{2}) = 4 + e$

Can you finish solving for $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ from here?

Comment: yeah, so simple. thanks :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help :)